# Return value from previous record if value is -1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, null

I've got a table that contains a LocationId field.  In some cases, where a record shares the same foreign key, the LocationId might come through as -1.

What I want to do is in my select query is in the case of this happening, the previous location.

Example data:

```
Record  FK     StartTime               EndTime          Location
1       110  2011/01/01 12.30        2011/01/01 6.10      456
2       110  2011/01/01 3.40         2011/01/01 4.00       -1
3       110  2011/01/02 1.00         2011/01/02 8.00      891
4       110  2011/01/02 5.00         2011/01/02 6.00       -1
5       110  2011/01/02 6.10         2011/01/02 6.30       -1
```

The -1 should come out as 456 for record 2, and 891 for record 4 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the entire result set

```
with tmp(Record ,FK ,StartTime ,EndTime ,Location)
as( select
1, 110 ,'2011/01/01 12:30', '2011/01/01 6:10', 456 union all select
2, 110 ,'2011/01/01 3:40', '2011/01/01 4:00', -1 union all select
3, 110 ,'2011/01/02 1:00', '2011/01/02 8:00', 891 union all select
4, 110 ,'2011/01/02 5:00', '2011/01/02 6:00', -1 union all select
5, 110 ,'2011/01/02 6:10', '2011/01/02 6:30', -1
)

-- ignore above this line
select curr.Record, curr.FK, curr.StartTime, curr.EndTime,
 case when curr.Location=-1 then prev.Location else curr.Location end Location
from tmp curr
outer apply 
 (select top 1 prev.location
 from tmp prev
 where curr.location=-1 and prev.FK=curr.FK
 and prev.starttime < curr.starttime
 and prev.location <> -1
 order by prev.starttime desc) prev
```

Comment: No, you're way off the mark.. The table has over 800k records.. so it needs to be robust, and not require FK values in the where statement..

Comment: @Matt I chose to go along `starttime`. You can swap for `record` if that is the order you require

Comment: Worked a charm.. Thanks for that Richard

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery. For example:

```
SELECT *
    , (SELECT TOP 1 Location
       FROM MyTable T2
       WHERE T2.Record <= T1.Record
       AND T2.FK = T1.FK
       AND T2.Location <> -1
       ORDER BY T2.Record DESC) AS BestLocation
FROM MyTable T1
```

Comment: Can you use `ORDER BY` in a subquery?

Comment: Yes, you can use `ORDER BY` in a subquery when using `TOP N`. However, as mattd noted, using `MAX` rather than `ORDER BY` will be faster.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod I mean the way you've used MAX() in your answer. The ORDER BY means that the results will need to be sorted, but using MAX() avoids the sort at the cost of another table scan. Depending on the size of the table and the available indices a table scan may well be faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Record,
    FK,
    StartTime,
    EndTime,
(
    SELECT
        Location
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE
        Record =
    ( 
        SELECT
            MAX(Record)
        FROM
            MyTable t2
        WHERE
            t2.Record =< t1.Record AND
            Location >= 0
    )
) 

FROM
    MyTable t1
```